# I don't understand why this Python code executes like this! [Project Euler]

Tags: python

I was just completing Project Euler, problem no. 1 for Python... the link to this is below:

http://projecteuler.net/problem=1

I came up with the following solution to this, in python...

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

def main():
    print("The answer will be calculated shortly...")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

n = 1000
n=-1

def isMultiple(i):
    if (i % 3 == 0) or (i % 5 == 0):
        if (i % 3 == 0) and (i % 5 == 0):
            return False
        else:
            return True


sum = 0
for i in range(3, n):
    if isMultiple(i):
        sum+=1
    print("The answer is... ", sum)
```

However, all that is given out, upon running this solution is:

```
[arch@archlinux Project Euler]$ python 1000-multi3or5.py
The answer will be calculated shortly...
[arch@archlinux Project Euler]$
```

I really don't understand what went wrong, could you help me with why? Many thanks if you took the time to even read this, especially if you bothered to help me. :)

Comment: So you set n=-1 and ofcourse your for loop executes zero times. Watch out for that :)

Comment: Oh dear, I am stupid. :P

Comment: Your program does not check command line parameters.

Comment: Then you want to do n -= 1

Comment: You set `n=-1` and then when `range(3,n)` is called, it won't go into the loop (and won't print anything)

Comment: Thanks guys, wow, I'm stupid. It should have been n-=1... I got the signs the wrong way around... *sigh*.

Comment: Try to use list comprehensions:`sum(i for i in range(1000) if not i%3 or not i%5)` and the problem is solved!

Comment: Why would you use a `main()` function that does nothing useful? Just leave it out if you don't want to put your code in it.

Comment: @segfolt The square brackets aren't even needed because without them then the expression is a generator, which is perfectly fine to use (and much more readable imo).

Comment: @Haidro: You're right. I edited my comment.

Answer (score 2):

Because the loop never happens:

```
n = 1000
n=-1
```

Then at the end:

```
for i in range(3, n):
```

You're running a range from 3 to -1.

```
In [4]: range(3, -1)
Out[4]: []
```

Change the line to:

```
n -= 1
```

And it should work:

```
In [9]: n = 20 # Just to show a smaller output - your n would be 999 obviously
   ...: sum = 0
   ...: for i in range(3, n):
   ...:     if isMultiple(i):
   ...:         sum+=1
   ...:     print("The answer is... ", sum)
   ...:     
('The answer is... ', 1)
('The answer is... ', 1)
('The answer is... ', 2)
('The answer is... ', 3)
('The answer is... ', 3)
('The answer is... ', 3)
('The answer is... ', 4)
('The answer is... ', 5)
('The answer is... ', 5)
('The answer is... ', 6)
('The answer is... ', 6)
('The answer is... ', 6)
('The answer is... ', 6)
('The answer is... ', 6)
('The answer is... ', 6)
('The answer is... ', 7)
('The answer is... ', 7)
```

Comment: I didn't realise I did that. Now I feel stupid. Thanks for helping out everyone!

Comment: No prob - typos always catch people out, especially when it's still valid code!

Comment: Yes, and you highlighted the other problem I made with the spam... oops, I fixed that too. Not a good day, well done sir, you really helped me a lot. :)